# c# insert polygon datatype into postgres

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postgresql, insert, polygon

My problem is the following:

I have a map with rooms on it and i have a asp.net project where i need to insert rooms into the postgres database.

I already got, roomid, roomtitle,... but now i need to insert a polygon.
It would be pretty cool if the admin inserting the rooms could define the polygon by pressing on a map.

here is a picture of the map:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnaDU.jpg

[image]

So my question is can i use something like html area coords and then use it somehow to get it into the database or am i comepletly wrong?

And what datatype can i use for the polygon in my roommodel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create struct represents point as a pair of doubles and model your
>   polygon as a list of that points. Once you have it you can map it to
>   polygon type in postgreSQL. Hope it helps.

Thanks that was part of the answer!

The only problem i habe now is how do i define the points by clicking on a map.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric types are available in PostgreSQL. You can find **polygon** type represented by lists of points. Perhaps this is what you are looking for.
More details in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html)

Comment: Okey i got the polygon in the postgres, but what is the best way to represent it in c# in my roommodel?

Comment: Create `struct` represents point as a pair of `double`s and model your polygon as a list of that points. Once you have it you can map it to polygon type in postgreSQL. Hope it helps.